# Align an element next to a centered element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place an image to the right of a second, centered image like so:

`|..........{IMAGE}{IMAGE2}..|`

All the answers on how to center images use `margin: auto;` or `<center>`, which results in Image2 being sent below Image1, or a surrounding div with `text-align: center;`, which I cannot get to center the Image.

I have a temporary solution using a left margin on Image1, and placing both images inside a `<center>`, but this results in the image not being centered if the window gets too small. Is there a better/ more elegant solution?

Comment: would be the great help for you to do a http://jsfiddle.net and share it whit us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can virtually reduce width of second image to zero with negative margin.

```
body {
  text-align:center;
}
img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
img + img {
  margin-right:-100px;/* equal to width of image , so it is virtually 0 width */
}
```

and

```
<body><!-- this can be a <p> container or else -->
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/100/" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/" />
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rkwGj

this works with any inline boxe as long as you know it's width